# Date Time based query in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have datetime stored in my table in the fields LeaveFrom and LeaveTo for leaves, something like

LeaveFrom = 05/26/2012 12:00:00 and LeaveTo = 06/30/2012.. and so on

From front end i am passing only Month and Year. So what will be the search condition for the same.

I need criteria for month and year wise searching. How many peoples applied for leave / or were absent  in the particular month.

**Thanks to all of you.. almost all were close to expected ...thanks,what i need  was a 'HINT'.. thanks a ton to all of you guys..**

Comment: Well that depends on what filter you're looking for. You need to elaborate some more.

Comment: What results do you want?  You're best advised to give example data and example results.

Comment: What if i would like to check how many guys were on leave in 5th month ?

Comment: I need the where condition part only. i have month and year in parameter..

Comment: For example, I have @month= 5 and @year =2012 and LeaveFrom = 05/26/2012 12:00:00. So How do I put a filter

Comment: @AmitRanjan People have worked pretty hard to answer your question - is there a reason one of the answers isn't acceptable?

Comment: @GermannArlington posted a better answer than the one i posted. Could you please change the chosen answer to his ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want all rows that has overlap between LeaveFrom and LeaveTo with the chosen month. I provided some sample dates as documentation.

```
declare @yourtable table(LeaveFrom datetime, LeaveTo datetime)
insert @yourtable values('2012-05-26 12:00:00', '2012-06-30')
insert @yourtable values('2012-01-26 12:00:00', '2012-12-30')
insert @yourtable values('2012-01-26 12:00:00', '2012-04-30')
insert @yourtable values('2012-05-26 12:00:00', '2012-12-30')
insert @yourtable values('2012-01-26 12:00:00', '2012-05-30')
insert @yourtable values('2012-06-26 12:00:00', '2012-12-30')
insert @yourtable values('2011-01-01 12:00:00', '2011-01-01')

declare @month tinyint = 5
declare @year int = 2012

-- calculate a data corresponding to month and year (2012-05-01)
declare @date datetime= dateadd(month, (@year-1900) * 12 + @month-1, 0)

select * from @yourtable
where datediff(month , LeaveFrom, @date) between 0 and datediff(month , LeaveFrom, LeaveTo)
```

EDIT: another possible way with same result:

```
select * from @yourtable
where @date between dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, LeaveFrom), 0) 
and dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, LeaveTo), 0)
```

Result:

```
LeaveFrom               LeaveTo
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-05-26 12:00:00.000 2012-06-30 00:00:00.000
2012-01-26 12:00:00.000 2012-12-30 00:00:00.000
2012-05-26 12:00:00.000 2012-12-30 00:00:00.000
2012-01-26 12:00:00.000 2012-05-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Is it just me or would not it be very inefficient because you will be calling dateadd() twice for EVERY record?

Comment: @GermannArlington you are right, but it is the only correct way to solve it, at least as far as i can tell. I surgest you test your solution with the examples in my data.

Comment: I just tried your dataset and selection and it gives me identical result. I don't really see why it should not?
Here is the code that I used...  


`declare @dateFrom datetime;
declare @dateTo datetime;

set @dateFrom = DateAdd(day, 0, DateAdd(month, @Month - 1, DateAdd(Year, @Year-1900, 0)));
set @dateTo = DATEADD("month", 1, @dateFrom);

SELECT *
FROM @yourtable 
WHERE LeaveFrom < @dateTo AND LeaveTo >= @dateFrom ;
`

Comment: My bad, your solution is correct, I had not seen that combination. Very good job indeed. I surgest you put that code in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to get a set of people who are on leave in a given Month/Year:

Here is the full updated code that some might find useful:

```
declare @dateFrom datetime  
declare @dateTo datetime 
set @dateFrom = DateAdd(day, 0, DateAdd(month, @Month - 1, 
                DateAdd(Year, @Year-1900, 0)))
set @dateTo = DATEADD("month", 1, @dateFrom)
SELECT * FROM @yourtable WHERE LeaveFrom < @dateTo AND LeaveTo >= @dateFrom
```

I make a point of calculating dates only once instead of calculating them for every selected row. The above code can be easily converted into a single SQL statement too. I write it like this to make it easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
where   (MONTH(LeaveFrom) = @Month 
        and YEAR(LeaveFrom) = @Year )
         OR
        (and MONTH(LeaveTo) = @Month 
        and YEAR(LeaveTo) = @Year )
```

Comment: I think you will need an OR between From and To dates

Comment: Not optimal if any of the columns is indexed. See the methods I posted

Comment: This only works if there is 0 or 1 months between LeaveFrom and LeaveTo

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM {your table name}
WHERE LeaveFrom >= CAST({input month} + '/1/' + {input year} AS DATETIME) AND
    LeaveTo <= DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, 1, CAST({input month} + '/1/' + {input year} AS DATETIME)))
```

And to be even more precise you could just subtract a minute instead of an entire day.

```
SELECT * FROM {your table name}
WHERE LeaveFrom >= CAST({input month} + '/1/' + {input year} AS DATETIME) AND
    LeaveTo < DATEADD(mm, 1, CAST({input month} + '/1/' + {input year} AS DATETIME))
```

You're starting to confuse everybody on what you want, but based on your last comment here is the query.

```
SELECT * FROM {your table name}
WHERE MONTH(LeaveFrom) = {input month} AND YEAR(LeaveFrom) = {input year}
```

Comment: You do not need to substract anything if you use < instead of <=

Comment: But you are performing date arithmetics under that assumption though.

Comment: @GermannArlington Because the assumption is made in the question based on the way the dates are shown.

Comment: The date format will change as soon as the server settings will change and these days you never know where your data centre will be next week. Your code will remain and produce incorrect results if that happens. For this reason alone one should never create dates by string concatenation (just from my personal experience, and I have been in this business for a long time).
P.S. I admit that Americans joke is not in the best taste (that is why I deleted it), but sometimes it really looks like it is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @month int
DECLARE @year int
SET @month = 7
SET @year = 2012

SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
(DATEPART(yy, LeaveFrom) = @year
AND DATEPART(mm, LeaveFrom) = @month) OR 
(DATEPART(mm, LeaveTo) = @month AND DATEPART(yy, LeaveTo) = @Year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Performancewise this will do best

```
declare @month int, @year int
select @month=6, @year=2012

select columns from table
where 
LeaveFrom>=Dateadd(month,(@year-1900)*12+@month-1,0) and
LeaveTo<Dateadd(month,(@year-1900)*12+@month,0)
```

You may also need to know how to simulate dateserial function in various ways
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/15788/10-ways-to-simulate-dateserial-function.aspx

Comment: what if LeaveFrom and LeaveTo are not in the same month, like in the example ?

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,LeaveFrom DATETIME
    ,LeaveTo DATETIME
    ,UserName VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO @Temp
VALUES (
    '2015-01-01'
    ,'2015-01-05'
    ,'Ramesh'
    )
    ,(
    '2015-01-07'
    ,'2015-01-09'
    ,'Suresh'
    )
    ,(
    '2015-01-03'
    ,'2015-01-06'
    ,'Dinesh'
    )
    ,(
    '2015-01-15'
    ,'2015-01-25'
    ,'Kamlesh'
    )
    ,(
    '2015-01-12'
    ,'2015-01-17'
    ,'Mohan'
    )

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM @Temp
WHERE '2015' BETWEEN YEAR(LeaveFrom)
        AND YEAR(LeaveTo)
    AND '1' BETWEEN MONTH(LeaveFrom)
        AND MONTH(LeaveTo)